# Ionic Deploy not updating app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app, and I am just trying to get ionic deploy working. I have the following errors -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY) ionic.cloud.min.js?ionicCachebuster=53854:6 Ionic Insights: Could not send insights. Error: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY(…)
```

but I don't think it's my app - because the debug prints out

```
Ionic Deploy: no updates available
```

Answer (score 0):

With these three steps it works for me:

1. `>_ ionic build`
2. `>_ ionic upload`
3. In https://apps.ionic.io -> deploy, in recent activity list,
   click on *"deploy"* in the last version.

Hope this help!